# How Can I write Python code for Temperature Convert to C orF using Frames, Entry Box and Label?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

[image: The Output Should be Like this Image.]

```
from tkinter import*

def convert2c():
    try:
        f = float(tempIN.get())
        c = (f-32)*5.0/9.0
        tempOUTc.set(c)
    except ValueError:
        pass

def convert2f():
    try:
        c = float(tempIN.get())
        f = c*9.0/5.0 + 32
        tempOUTf.set(f)
    except ValueError:
        pass

root = Tk() 
f = root    
root.title("Temperature Converter")
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(500,200))
topFrm = Frame(root, width=500, height=80, bg="#e01111")
midFrm = Frame(root, width=500, height=150, bg="#795fb5")
btmFrm = Frame(root, width=500, height=100)
btmL = Frame(btmFrm, width=250, height=100, bg="#4117a5")
btmR = Frame(btmFrm, width=250, height=100, bg="#3f454f")
topFrm.grid(row=0, sticky="W")
midFrm.grid(row=1)
btmFrm.grid(row=3)
btmL.grid(row=2, column=0)
btmR.grid(row=2, column=2)

tempIN = StringVar()
tempOUTc = StringVar()
tempOUTf = StringVar()

Label(f, text="Temperature Converter\n A number in temperature degree is converted into another as one of the button is clicked").grid(column=0, row=0)
Label(f, text="Enter a Temperature").grid(column=0, row=1)
Entry(f, textvariable=tempIN, width=10) .grid(column=0, rowspan=1, row=1, sticky=W)
Button(f, text=" to Celsius", command=convert2c) .grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=W)
Button(f, text=" to Fahrenheit", command=convert2f) .grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=W) 
Label(f, textvariable=tempOUTc) .grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=W)
Label(f, textvariable=tempOUTf) .grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=W)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The Output SHoudl be attached Image. Thanks in advance for your help...

Comment: you forgot to ask a question

Comment: Please fix the code formatting. What exactly is the problem? What is the provided code doing, and what should it be doing instead?

Comment: Kindly Check my code. How can I get the exact output like attached Image ?